# Installer is not showing all the permissions I request (Android)

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

This is my section of permissions of my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.adelco.ventamovil"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

But when I try to install the package, the wizzard only shows the Internet and Write External Storage permissions.

The DDMS perspective throws this warning message when I install the application:

> 03-28 10:48:36.627: WARN/PackageManager(144): Not
>   granting permission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES to package
>   com.adelco.ventamovil (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe44)
>
> 03-28 10:48:36.627: WARN/PackageManager(144): Not granting permission
>   android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES to package com.adelco.ventamovil
>   (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe44)

What is happening here....?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry,

Install, delete packages are system permissions. You won't be able to obtain them unless your app is signed with the device's platform certificate (which is impossible unless you have access to the manufacturer's signing cert).

As you can imagine, that'd be a serious security problem if an arbitrary application could silently install other applications.

The best you can do is send the user to the package install page and let them take action if they wish. Take a look at this action intent you can send to start this process for install,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE

and for uninstall,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE

Answer (score 4):

`INSTALL_PACKAGES` and `DELETE_PACKAGES` are either in the group `signature` or `signatureOrSystem` and thus can't be granted to an "ordinary" app:

> A permission that the system grants only to applications that are in the Android system image or that are signed with the same certificates as those in the system image

See [android:protectionLevel](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).

Comment: Wait... But it was working ok until yesterday... And It should work in the emulator?

Comment: @Desenfoque what do you mean exactly by "it worked"? You could install or remove packages? I hardly can believe that. It only would have to work in the emulator if the signing certificate would be included there, but I doubt that.

Answer (score -1):

Did you put your permissions like that?

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```